# Twitterizer, cannot logout

Tags: twitter, logout, twitterizer

I am using twitterizer to authenticate users.  everything works fine except everytime I try to logout, I got "bad request" back.  I also tested the sample application I downloaded from twitterizer.com, try the logout.aspx page, couldn't get that working.

```
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();


            OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens()
            {
                AccessToken = _twitterAccessToken,
                AccessTokenSecret = _twitterAccessTokenSecret,
                ConsumerKey = _twitterConsumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = _twitterConsumerSecret
            };

            TwitterResponse<TwitterErrorDetails> twitterResponse = TwitterAccount.EndSession(tokens, null);
             var result = twitterResponse.Result;


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

twitterResponse.Result always returns back "BadRequest", I refreshed the page, still logged in.

Comment: what do you have in your Index action on your Home controller? Please paste some form of the code, that my be where the problem is.

Comment: shanabus, sorry didn't make it clear. I edit my question. twitterResponse.Result = "BadRequest", its not the homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end session endpoint will have no effect unless the user logs into twitter during the authentication process. If the user logs in and, after logged in, authorizes your application, the end session method will do nothing.

The API provides only very limited control over the user's session. This has been a big issue for a very long time.

Comment: thank you so much,  do I still need those code? Can I just use FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

Comment: If I were you, I'd still call the EndSession, but make it no-fail code. This way you'll log the user out of Twitter when you can.